# Error while extracting value from database aiosqlite python, ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite, python-asyncio

I'm writing telegram bot in python with sqlite as database. I use aiosqlite as framework for connecting to database and executing values. In database I have 3 columns and it looks like:

```
user_id, user_name, balance
802123124,@toppythonguy,0
79124142124,@None,0
```

And when I get balance using user_id by this function it works fine

```
async def tryer(userid, column="user_id"):
    sql_connection = await aiosqlite.connect("users.db")
    sql_cursor = await sql_connection.cursor()
    await sql_cursor.execute(f'''SELECT balance FROM users WHERE {column} == {userid}''')
    user_balance = await sql_cursor.fetchall()
    await sql_connection.close()
    if not user_balance:
        return False
    else:
        return user_balance
```

But when I'm trying same code with username (like: @Goodfella) I'm getting error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

I've tried some solutions from stackowerflow but none of them works form me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you’re using an f-string to construct your SQL statement. When you try to use `user_name` you end up with

```
SELECT BALANCE FROM users WHERE user_name = @toppythonguy
```

SQLite uses `@` (along with a few other characters) to indicate a bound parameter, in this case one named `toppythonguy`. It’s expecting you to provide the value when you call `execute`.

Wrapping the value in quotes should help. It would probably break your `user_id` query, though, since you’d be using a string instead of an integer.

The real fix is to always use a bound parameter.

```
await sql_cursor.execute(f”SELECT balance FROM users WHERE {column} = ?”, userid)
```

As a general rule of thumb you don’t want allow user provided values into a SQL query that you construct. Using your original query, imagine if someone submitted this as their username

```
1; DELETE FROM users
```

Bound parameters are the way to avoid that. Depending on how `column` is populated you may need to do something there, too, but as long as the code that calls `tryer` selects it from a predetermined list you should be fine.